# How to render props from parent component to child?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components, ejs

I'm trying to loop through an array and send a title & description to a child component. However, the child component isn't recognized the props I have assigned to it in the parent component.

News.js:

```
const AllNews = [
{
    title: 'Reverse The Online Gambling Ban',
    description: 'The MPA comes with three different sizes of foam and silicone tips and a carrying pouch.'
},
{
    title: 'Successful Myspace Profile',
    description: 'All users on MySpace will know that there are millions of people out there.'
},
{
    title: 'Home Audio Recording For Everyone',
    description: 'The number of friends and acquaintances will grow in a large number. This is what you should be looking for.'
},
{
    title: 'Buying Used Electronic Test Equipment',
    description: 'People after all will make friends after reading about you. If you have an ugly profile, there is no way they will want to date you.'
}
]

export default function News() {
const classes = useStyles();

const listNews = AllNews.forEach(news => {
    <Singlenews title={news.title} description={news.description}/>
})

return (
    <div>
        {listNews}
    </div>
)
```

}

Singlenews.js:

```
export default function Singlenews(props) {
const classes = useStyles();
const {title, description} = props

return (
<div className={classes.group4}>
  <div className={classes.bitmap}/>
    <div className={classes.flexCol}>
      <div className={classes.reverseTheOnlineG}>
      {title}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.group4}>
        <p className={classes.theMpaComesWithT}>
         {description}
       </p>
      <div className={classes.oval}/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
)
```

}

Comment: My doofy asz wasnt returning anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part here:

```
const listNews = AllNews.forEach(news => {
    <Singlenews title={news.title} description={news.description}/>
})
```

you are looping over each item in `AllNews` and creating `Singlenews` components using the `forEach` function.  Thats definitely the right idea, the problem is that the `forEach` function returns `undefined` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). So `listNews` actually equals `undefined` in this case.

My recommendation would be to look at the `map` function in JavaScript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  This function maps a callback to each element of the array and returns a new array, containing the return values from the callback.  So in this case, you could map a `<SingleNews>` component to each element in `AllNews`, passing props down just like you already have it:

```
const listNews = AllNews.map(news => {
    return <Singlenews title={news.title} description={news.description}/>
})
```

This way, `listNews` is an array of `<Singlenews>` items like you intended, with the props correctly set. Not a problem with the props, a problem with the loop!

Comment: Yes excellent thank you! I had just solved the problem with the exact solution you have posted. I really appreciate you taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

try this `const listNews = AllNews.map(news => <Singlenews title={news.title} description={news.description}/>);`

instead of `const listNews = AllNews.forEach(news => { <Singlenews title={news.title} description={news.description}/> })`